# For Loop Not Iterating the Right Amount of times

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


      int rnd = list[modo];

      }

   return 1;
}
```

This code compiles fine, I just have a question as to why the for loop isn't iterating till `size < i`  Where i is the same size as the integer argument that gets passed int.
It's supposed to keep printing `%d` until it reaches size `i` but it only prints one random number.

I'm trying to get it to print the amount of random numbers that are passed as an argument. 
So if you enter `./main 3` to run the program for example it prints: `0 4 5` or `./main 4` it prints: `2 1 5 6`

Comment: `argc` is the number of arguments, not the value of the argument. The first argument is `argv[1]`, and it is a string (`char*`). And you have _many_ other issues in your program.

Comment: Sorry, but If you're going to edit the question as I point out flaws and invalidate my answer, then I am not going to answer.

Comment: Your answer came off more as a comment, but that doesn’t mean it wasn’t helpful.

Comment: There is a `return 0` inside the for statement block, this exits the main function and ends the program, remove this line. (And change the last line `return 1` to `return 0`).

Comment: @isrnick very modest of you to comment that. You should answer the question so I can accept it as correct. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @isrnick, I guess it did help with printing a number the correct amount of times but it is now printing the same random number , ie: ‘6 6 6 6 6’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `return 0` inside the for statement block, this exits the `main` function and ends the program, remove this line. (And change the last line `return 1` to `return 0`.)

Comment: Thanks. This helped iterate correctly. Do you know why it is now printing the same number n amount of time such as ‘5 5 5 5’ for an argument of 4 instead of 4 random numbers like ‘2 4 3 1’

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` sets the seed that is used to generate random numbers, and it should be sufficient to call it once in the `main`, there is no need to place it inside the for statement. What should be inside the for is the call to the `rand` function to acquire random numbers to be printed, like this `rnd = rand() % 10;`.

Answer (score 1):

isrnick answer is spot on. Anyway, the program has **many** other problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( int argc, int *argv[] )  { // <--- Must be int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      srand(time(NULL));             // <--- Warning, you need a cast here.   
      int list[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // <--- Why?      
      int modo = rand() %11;         // <--- Must be %10 if desired max is 9   
      int rnd = list[modo];          // <--- This will be a single value for the program
      int arr[argc];                 // <--- VLAs? Why?
      int i = argv[1];               // <--- Warning, C string to int... you need a conversion function
      int size = 0;

      for (size = 0; size < i; size++){ // <--- Do yourself a favor, use i as the looping variable
          srand(time(NULL));         // <--- One srand per program
          printf("%d \n", rnd);      // <--- always print the same number
          return 0;                  // <--- Terminate program here? No, no.
      }

   return 1;                         // <--- If no error, return 0.
}
```

Minimal fixed version (no checks):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int rnd = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", rnd);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

More controls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int n;
    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%i", &n) != 1) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int rnd = rand() % 10;
        printf("%d ", rnd);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```